# How to split node connections?

Tags: interface, node-editor

In a tutorial a guy split a line like this:

[image]

I have try left click and right click but nothing works.

Answer (score 33):

That is called a *[reroute node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Compositing_Nodes#Reroute)*.

Hold <kbd>RMB</kbd> (<kbd>LMB</kbd> in 2.7x) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging your cursor over the noodle(s) to create one.

[image]

Note that its only use is making node setups less tangled and easier to work with, it  doesn't affect the result of the node setup at all.

Comment: If this answered your question, feel free to [mark it as accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: It's right mouse button in 2.81